# Translate Vue element in asp.net core web app

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, razor

I recentyl inherented a Web App in work made in ASP.Net Core 2.2 and the Views are made with Razor and Vue, I was asked to add multi languagem support to the app, so already created all the resx files, and added IViewLocalizer to the Views, now I have a problem that is the Vue variables, I never worked with Vue so I would ask your help in this part.

I have a v-for

```
<div v-for="Order in client.Orders" class="card-block border">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <h5 class="text-sm">@Localizer["Order"] {{Order.OrderId}}</h5>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-light text-center">
        <em class="text-sm">{{Order.State}}</em>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-sm table-borderless text-sm">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Localizer["Location"]</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{Order.PaymentLocation}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Localizer["Destination Country"]</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{Order.DestCountry}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I have access to the {{Order.State}} to translate the value?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can not use asp.net core `IViewLocalizer` to localize the data in Vue, because the client side codes and server side codes are in different lifetime. You may need to have a Api for translate the words then return it to vue.

Comment: Or you could have your template in razor page (.cshtml) as script and translate it using dotnet IViewLocalizer and loaded to vue componenet as string template.